# React prevent useContext from rerendering when only use the dispatch callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am building a component tree, where the controller of a state could be deeply nested in the tree, or nested in the siblings of the consumer of the state. Therefore I use `Context.Provider` to wrap the dispatch function and the state at the top level, then call `useContext` inside controller function to access the dispatch function.

Now the problem is, when I call dispatch function in controller, it will cause a change of the state of `Context.Provider`, then cause the controller component to rerender. Since the controller only uses the dispatch function, I think the rerender should be avoided.

An example:

```js
const Context = React.createContext();

const AppContext = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ state, setState }}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

const ControllerButton = () => {
  const { setState } = useContext(Context); // only setState is called
  const onClick = () => {
    setState(oldState => !oldState);
  }
  // assume there are some other expensive computations so I would like to prevent it from rerendering
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Toggle</button>;
}

const App() => {
  return (
    <AppContext>
      <ControllerButton/>
      {/* ...consumers of state */}
    </AppContext>
  );
}
```

Here I have several questions:

1. For my needs (caller of dispatch function and consumer of state lives remotely in a complex react component tree), should I use `useContext` to implement it? Are there better options?
2. If I have to use `useContext`, one way to do so is to split it into 2 contexts. For example:

```js
const StateContext = React.createContext();
const SetStateContext = React.createContext();

const AppContext = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ state }}>
      <SetStateContext.Provider value={{ setState }}>
        {children}
      </SetStateContext.Provider>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

However, I found most implementations do not do so. Is it a good practice?

3. Alternatively, I can also make the rerender cost small enough, such as use `React.memo`:

```js
const ControllerButtonInner({setState}) {
  const onClick = () => {
    setState(oldState => !oldState);
  }
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Toggle</button>;
}

}
const ControllerButton = () => {
  const { setState } = useContext(Context);
  
  return React.memo(<ControllerButtonInner setState={setState}/>);
}
```

Is it a good practice?

4. Or, is there any other approach to prevent it from rerender?

Comment: fyi https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156

Comment: useContext rerenders all subscribers when the state is changed. There is nothing wrong with any of your approaches. There is however an extra route you could take by using redux or something similair. This would prevent the rerender depending on how you manage your state. I think at the end of the day you need to weigh up the performance hit that you are getting from this implementation and see if it s really that bad.